# How to group states into regions when there is no region table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, grouping

My data set has states as a column but no region column to group the states by. I would like to group the states into standard census bureau regions to get the count of employee IDs by region:

[image]

```
Select COUNT(DISTINCT Empl_ID) AS Employee_Count,
STATE
FROM Employee_Table
GROUP BY STATE
```

I tried exporting the query and then sorting in Excel but the dataset is too large for Excel.

Comment: Create a table based on the data provided in the image (i.e. `create table region_state (region varchar(30), state varchar(30)`), then do a join with Employee_Table.

Comment: @ahmed, could you provide an abbreviated example using some of the data from the image? Then I'll fill in the rest. Thank you

Comment: Yes, of course, see the posted answer.

Comment: The image appears to be a screenshot of text. Please do not put images of text in your question. Copy the text, paste it in the question, and format it appropriately. Links die, making your question less useful for future visitors. Also, if it's pasted as text we can copy/paste the data into our answers without have to transcribe a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table based on the data provided in the image:

```
create table region_state (region varchar(30), state varchar(30));
insert into region_state values
('Northen Region', 'New Jersey'),
('Northen Region', 'New York'),
('Midwest Region', 'Illinois')
...;
```

Now we can use a join query to get the region for each employee state as the following:

```
Select COUNT(DISTINCT E.Empl_ID) AS Employee_Count,
       R.region
FROM Employee_Table E JOIN region_state R
ON E.state = R.state
GROUP BY R.region
```

If there are no duplicates in the `Empl_ID` column (and that is the typical case, i.e. `Empl_ID` is the primary key of the table) you would use `COUNT(E.Empl_ID)`, with no need for `DISTINCT`.